# CHAP authentication attempt rejected due to expired or unknown challenge value

Tags: unicorn

we are having an issue with unicorn sync run through octopus deployment process that is using MicroChap dll and shared secret. Everything was working fine and unicorn sync was working fine.
Then we got production master, web databases to qa. We then ran the deployment process and it failed in unicorn sync process step. We are still able to go /unicorn.aspx page and do sync and that works fine.
It is not syncing from the deployment process. We reverted back the web database and the deployment process unicorn sync started working fine. we have shared secret in Unicorn.UI.config

```
 <authenticationProvider type="Unicorn.ControlPanel.Security.ChapAuthenticationProvider, Unicorn">
    <SharedSecret>somesharesecret</SharedSecret>
    <!--<SharedSecret></SharedSecret> Uncomment this line and provide a strong randomized shared secret here. At least 64 characters is recommended, for example https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm -->
    <!-- Authentication challenges are stored in a Sitecore database. You can select which database here. No item installs/templates are required. -->
    <ChallengeDatabase>web</ChallengeDatabase>
    <!-- 
                Writes the reason why failed automated tool authentications failed to the Sitecore logs.
                Will result in writing your shared secret to the logs as part of the signature base,
                so you can disable it if you wish.
            -->
    <WriteAuthFailuresToLog>true</WriteAuthFailuresToLog>
  </authenticationProvider>
```

We have enabled WriteAuthFailuresToLog to true. When we did that, we see the following messages in the log file.

13048 00:17:40 WARN  [Unicorn-Auth] CHAP challenge store removed expired challenge 48337.......5c40950.
13048 00:17:40 WARN  [Unicorn-Auth] CHAP challenge store rejected 48337.......5c40950 because it was unknown.
13048 00:17:40 WARN  [Unicorn-Auth] CHAP authentication attempt rejected due to expired or unknown challenge value.

Can someone please help in understanding why changing the web database caused unicorn sync to fail from deployment process. Where are these challenge items stored? and is there way to update or get this working?
Any help in this regard will be helpful.

**Update**
We did look at the /sitecore/system/Authentication Challenges node and it was there but had no children. We deleted that node and ran the process, and the process recreated that node. However the error still persisted last night.

We dropped the issue last night and went ahead fixing some other unrelated issues and did some publish of site items. Today when we tried to troubleshoot outside of the deployment process it successfully synced. Then we reran the deployment process and it worked too. So not sure what made it work, maybe some expiry of challenges that got it to work again.

Here is the error that we received in the deployment process

Sync-Unicorn: Preparing authorization for https://$siteurl/unicorn.aspx?verb=Sync&configuration=
URL: https://$siteurl/unicorn.aspx?verb=Challenge
Sync-Unicorn: Received challenge: challenge
Sync-Unicorn: Created signature $signature, executing Sync...
Error Unable to authorize request, ensure that your shared secrets match. (We did make sure shared secrets matched as the first step)

This is syncing fine from deployment process now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not uncommon for the challenge store to remove expired items. This happens on a regular basis. Can you provide more details around the failed sync? What's the error?

Comment: The challenges are stored under `/sitecore/system/Authentication Challenges`. While I can't really know how you ended up here, perhaps cleaning this out will sort things out.

Comment: I recently had the exact same issue. Challenges were deleted before they could be completed. Simply publishing everything solved the issue. Nothing else helped.